# Emacs python-mode language formatting does not reapply on buffer on newly typed text

Tags: python, buffers, colors, formatting

When I open a `.py` file for the first time
the formatting is perfect, colors match special words as expected in Python

But when I type new text in the buffer, it inherits the color of the same character my cursor was when I started typing
regardless of Python formatting.

Expected behavior would be that after each key press that result in new characters being added to the buffer
the Python formatting would reapply immediately.

My workaround is to run `M-x python-mode` which does a one-time fix for the buffer formatting until I add new characters once again.

How could this be fixed?

Comment: elpy may be a better python mode.

Comment: elpy looks nice but I still have to run `M-x elpy-mode` to re-apply python formatting.
for example if I type `raise Exception()` it will remain grey (or will inherit colors from the last place my cursor was at) until I reapply formatting as explained.